# filtering results in components

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have hardcoded data that is being retrieved by a service.

and a component that sends that data to another component to render a list.

i also have 2 html Select in a different component. 
i can send the Select values.

what i'm trying to do is filter the data i received from the service according to
the Select output.

here is the data model:

```
export interface ProductModel{
  ProductID:number,
  ProductTitle:string,
  Description:string,
  ProductImage:string
  Price:number,
  PriceLabel:string,
  ProductTags:number[]
}
```

Explanation on how the filter is suppose to work:
i have an array of gifts/items. each gift has productTags.
when i select from a  i send tag numbers and filter gifts accordingly.

code **Gift.Service**, sends the data:

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as data from "./products.json";

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";

import { ProductModel } from "../models/product.model";

@Injectable()
export class GiftsService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getStoreList(): ProductModel[] {
    let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return (<any>data).gifts;
  } 

}
```

code **GiftManager**, recives the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { GiftsService } from './../../services/gifts.service';

import { ProductModel } from './../../models/product.model';

@Component({
  selector: "gifts-manager",
  template: `
    <div class="manger-container">
      <filter-manager [genderFilter]="genderFilter" [priceFilter]="priceFilter" (filterGifts)="filterGifts($event)"></filter-manager>
      <div *ngIf="gifts ; let giftsList; else loading">
        <gift-list [giftList]="giftsList"></gift-list>
      </div>
      <ng-template #loading>Loading</ng-template>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./gifts-manager.component.css"]
})
export class GiftsManagerComponent implements OnInit {
  gifts:ProductModel[];
  priceFilter:object[];
  genderFilter:object[];

  constructor(private giftsService:GiftsService) {
    this.gifts =  giftsService.getStoreList();
    this.priceFilter = giftsService.getPriceFilter();
    this.genderFilter = giftsService.getGenderFilter();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  //*********** this is the messy part *********  

  filterGifts(event=""):Observable<ProductModel[]>{
    let tempGifts = this.giftsService.getStoreList();
    if (event === ""){return Observable.of(tempGifts)};
    const filters = Object.values(event);
    const filtersValue = filters.map(filter => filter.value)

    const filteredGifts = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < filtersValue.length; c++) {
        if(filtersValue[c] !== "")
          for (var i = 0; i < tempGifts.length; i++) {
            if(tempGifts[i].ProductTags.filter(tag => tag === filtersValue[c]).length)
            filteredGifts.push(tempGifts[i]);
          }
    }
    console.log(filteredGifts)
    return Observable.of(filteredGifts);
  }
//*************************************************
}
```

I've been stuck on this for hours, trying to use observables and getting confused on how to do basic filter onnested arrays, i think i'm able to filter. 
but it feels so messy.

how do i filter and how do i pass the filtered gifts to the component list?

Comment: Hi Itay welcome to stackoverflow :) Your post is well done, you've put some code, explained your problem, it's great. But if you want to have more chance to get some help, you might want to create a small repro of it on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5) or even better, on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) this way other people willing to help can try something live and share you what they did very easily. ;)
Let me know if you update your post with one of the 2 and I might try something :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your gifts is JSON.

Ok this is not easy to fix I know it.

```
<div> <input type="text" (keyup)="filterGift($event)" /></div>
<div *ngFor let gift of filter>
```

And in component

```
filterGift(event: string) {
    this.filter = this.gifts.filter(gift =>
        gift.ProductTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}
```

This is all I can give you for an example.

Comment: You prob tried something like this before this is an example out my project. Searched really long to fix it. Not that easy..